# Google Adwords API

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I just have a quick question to see if this is possible with the Google Adwords API or if there is a better solution / service out there that I could use.

What we need to do is generate a Google Adwords report each month with some statistics.  We need the report to automatically pull the following things:

- # of clicks
- Cost
- Average Ad Position
- Top 5 Keywords Clicked

Then, it should also compare how it did from the previous month and then provide a graph of the past 6 months activity.

Is this all possible?  I am waiting for the adwords login from my company so I can go in and request the key and play around with it but in the mean time I just wanted to ask and see what you guys think.  Is something like this difficult or pretty straight forward?  Is there maybe a service already out there that does something like this?  This will be for over 100 accounts.

What do you guys recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of this is possible using the API but the API may be overkill. The automated reporting features in Adwords are very customisable and you can have them generated at regular intervals and emailed to you with the data you mention.

You can find info on setting them up here: http://adwords.google.com/support/aw/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=12299

I used to have a number of python scripts that would generate all sorts of pretty graphs from the early Adwords API. It wasn't until a few years later I realised the automated reports could do it all and much more.

Comment: Thank you!  I have to say though, I can't find very many customization options - maybe I am missing something.  I read all of the articles though.

Answer (score 0):

Try [AdWords Scripts](https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/). With those, you could write a 30-line piece of Javascript, have it dump the output and graphs into a Google spreadsheet, and automatically execute once a month while emailing you about it. They have a few tutorials on the website that do very similar things.